# /usr/include/zconf.h attribute became ----------

Tags: linux, file, permissions

after running yum update /usr/include/zconf.h became

```
    ---------- 1 root root 9544 May  6 16:43 /usr/include/zconf.h
    chmod 0766 /usr/include/zconf.h
    chmod: changing permissions of `/usr/include/zconf.h': Permission denied
```

I cannot change the attribute even under root. How to change the attribute ?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix permissions:

```
sudo su -
# enter root password...

chmod 755 /usr /usr/include
chmod 644 /usr/include/zconf.h
```

You need `wx` permissions to the parent directory of the file:

- `x` - to read directory contents
- `w` - to modify files within the directory